# Calculating dollar impact of removing one customer with the next customer moves up using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to calculate the revenue/dollar impact of removing certain customer from my table, any help would be appreciated!

This is the cleaned up table that I have -

| Received_at | Customer | Click | Match_Bundle_ID | Revenue | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | John | 1 | 12301 | 10.5 | 1 |
| 1/1 | Mike | 0 | 12301 | 9.2 | 2 |
| 1/1 | Mary | 0 | 12301 | 6.3 | 3 |
| 1/1 | Bob | 0 | 12301 | 6.1 | 4 |
| 1/2 | Lisa | 0 | 12302 | 7.6 | 1 |
| 1/2 | John2 | 0 | 12302 | 7.1 | 2 |
| 1/2 | Mary | 0 | 12302 | 5.9 | 3 |
| 1/2 | Mike | 0 | 12302 | 5.8 | 4 |
| 1/3 | John | 0 | 12303 | 6.9 | 1 |
| 1/3 | Mike | 1 | 12303 | 5.3 | 2 |
| 1/3 | Mary | 0 | 12303 | 5.1 | 3 |
| 1/3 | Bob | 0 | 12303 | 3.1 | 4 |
| 1/4 | Mike | 1 | 12304 | 8.9 | 1 |
| 1/4 | John | 0 | 12304 | 8.4 | 2 |
| 1/4 | John2 | 1 | 12304 | 7.8 | 3 |
| 1/4 | Bob | 0 | 12304 | 6.5 | 4 |
| 1/4 | Lisa | 0 | 12304 | 5.5 | 5 |
| 1/4 | Mary | 0 | 12304 | 3.1 | 6 |
| 1/5 | Bob | 0 | 12305 | 3.5 | 1 |
| 1/5 | John2 | 1 | 12305 | 2.3 | 2 |
| 1/5 | John | 0 | 12305 | 2.1 | 3 |

I would like to calculate the revenue impact of removing customer John and John2.

The assumptions are as follows -

1. Revenue will only be generated if a click happens
2. When one customer is removed within a match bundle, the next customer automatically moves up (only within the bundle)
3. Assume click will happen following the rank, so the next customer who moves up will inherent the click (hence generating the revenue)
4. In a set match bundle, we could get 0 clicks, 1 click or multiple clicks

Based on the above assumptions, after removing customer John and John2, the new table would look like this -

[image: Table 2 - After removing customer John and John2]

So the result should be:

Revenue before -

[image: Revenue 1]

Revenue after removing John and John2 -

[image: Revenue 2]

Therefore the revenue dollar impact would be $34.8 - $28.7 = $6.1

I am having trouble realizing this using SQL query, I'm hoping if anyone here can help with what is the best command to use here with this.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful for people trying to answer if data sample is included as text rather then image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm super new here, still trying to figure out how to add a table/data sample without messing up the format.

Comment: Do you have both data-sets i.e. original and one after removing a customer and ONLY question is to get difference in revenue, or are you also looking for a way/query to return data-set after a customer removal?

Comment: I am looking for both. The only thing I have is the cleaned up table with ranks. step 1 - get the return table after removing John and John2, step 2 - calculate the revenue difference. Thank you!

Comment: There are multi DB tags, please do not tag mutliple DBs. Modify tags to retain only tag for DB you are working on or are looking solution for.

Comment: Edited, I am using snowflakes

Comment: Your output/new table shown as based on original data, does not seem to match with assumption  - "When one customer is removed, the next customer is automatically moves up" or there is some more assumptions conditions not specified here.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear with the click inherent rule. The next customer would move up while maintaining the click in its original spot. For instance, in bundle 12301, John was ranked #1 with a click, when John was removed, original #2 Mike would move up and inherent that click, and they are the new #1 in the updated table.

Comment: Yes, same as per that rule, please validate your cleaned up output, it does-not match.

Comment: Seems like the up movement is grouped within match_bundle_id and no movement for rest of the rows below.

Comment: Oh I see your point. Yes, the movement is grouped within match_bundle_id. The output is correct but I'll update the main post for assumption #2 - when a customer is removed within a match bundle, the next customer automatically moves up (within that bundle).

Answer (score 1):

The query uses data from CTE (Common Table Expression),
which can be replaced with actual table.

Query creates filtered data as per provided assumptions of pushing 'click'
value up within a group of match_bundle_id after a customer is removed from that group.

First, it generates data set with valid 'click' i.e. click that should replace
the originals after data is pushed up.
Then, data set is generated with filtered customers without click column.

Above two data-sets are joined based on a generated key column.

Once we have filtered data-set and original data,
they are used to get relevant SUMs.

```
with data_cte (received_at, customer, click, match_bundle_id,revenue,rank) 
as
(select * from values // Replace with (select * from actual table)
('1-Jan','John',1,12301,10.5,1),
.
.
... Truncated...
('5-Jan','John',0,12305,2.1,3)
), cte_click_1 as ( // CTE including only relevant clicks
select match_bundle_id,click,rank,
count_if(customer not in ('John','John2')) 
over (partition by match_bundle_id) cnt 
from data_cte, table(generator(rowcount=>1))
qualify row_number() 
over (partition by match_bundle_id order by rank) <= cnt
order by match_bundle_id
), cte_click_rank as ( // CTE with click and row_number to use for joining
select row_number() over(order by seq4())rn,
cte_click_1.* from cte_click_1,  table(generator(rowcount=>1))
), cte_excluded_customer as ( // CTE with data without excluded customer
select row_number() over(order by seq4())rn,
received_at, customer, match_bundle_id,revenue 
from data_cte,  table(generator(rowcount=>1))
where customer not in ('John','John2')
), cte_filtered_customers as ( // CTE with final filtered customers
select a.received_at, a.customer, b.click, a.match_bundle_id,a.revenue
from cte_excluded_customer a, cte_click_rank b
where a.rn = b.rn
order by match_bundle_id
), cte_sum_orig as ( // CTE with SUM of original revenue
select match_bundle_id, sum(revenue) sum_o from data_cte
where click>0
group by match_bundle_id order by match_bundle_id
), cte_sum_revised as ( // CTE with SUM of revised revenue
select match_bundle_id, sum(revenue) sum_r from cte_filtered_customers
where click>0
group by match_bundle_id order by match_bundle_id
)
select sum(sum_o) - sum(sum_r) revenue_diff
from cte_sum_orig a left outer join  cte_sum_revised b
on a.match_bundle_id = b.match_bundle_id
;
+--------------+
| REVENUE_DIFF |
|--------------|
|          6.1 |
+--------------+
```